# ILO Update : Which version should we select?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware, hp, vmware-vsphere, hp-proliant

We have a **HP ProLiant DL160 Gen 8 server**, with **VMWare ESXi 6.0.0** actually installed on it.

We started to update it to VMWare ESXi 6.5, but the upgrade stopped, stating that **we need to update the HP ILO** before going forward.

Our current HP ILO is 600.9.0.2.8-1OEM.600.0.0.2159203

So here is my question : **Which ILO should I select** ?

- Should I pick an ILO version from this page (related to my **ACTUAL** version of ESXi 6.0) ?
  http://vibsdepot.hpe.com/hpe/dec2016/
- Should I pick an ILO version from this page (related to my D**ESIRED** version of ESXi 6.5) ?
  http://vibsdepot.hpe.com/hpe/jan2017/

Thank you very much,

Comment: How are you performing these updates? vSphere Upgrade Manager? What is generating the error?

Comment: @ewwhite : These update were initiated in command-line. I've found the solution (see below in this thread). Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's telling you about the ILO package. It's rare to see any mention of it individually. Is this from vSphere Upgrade Manager? There may be an option to uninstall vendor-specific packages during the VUM update.

If you are performing this via the VUM and have the HP VIBs integrated into the workflow, use the newest. There are only 3 packages in the bundle, and they should all be of the same version and upgraded together. So please install the 6.5 packages.

[image]

If you are running this upgrade manually using the offline VIBs for ESXi 6.5, do the same thing...

The bundled packages should be installed at the same time. Install the packages that correspond to your new version.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for your answers. I've finally found a safe way to **upgrade to ESXi 6.5 and to update the HP ILO in the same time** : I used the OEM HPE image, for which the offline bundle can be downloaded from the VMWare website (link below)

It worked perfectly (and so fast : almost 10 seconds !). My ESXi has now **switched from 6.0 to 6.5**, and the https:/ESXI-IP-ADDRESS/ui is working perfect.

Here is the process for everyone who needs it :

- Download the Offline Bundle from : https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=OEM-ESXI65-HPE&productId=614
- Upload the Offline Bundle in your datastore (do NOT change its name - do NOT unzip it)
- Shut down your VM's
- Put your ESXi in "Maintenance mode"
- Manually Start the SSH service
- Type the following PUTTY command-line (assuming that your datastore is named "datastore1" in my example) :

  ```
  esxcli software profile update -p HPE-ESXi-6.5.0-OS-Release-650.9.6.0.28 -d /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/VMware-ESXi-6.5.0-OS-Release-4564106-HPE-650.9.6.0.28-Nov2016-depot.zip
  ```
- You should get "The update completed sucessfully, but the system needs to be rebooted for the changes to be effective"
- Type the following command-line to Reboot :

  ```
  reboot -f
  ```
- Connect to https:/ESXI-IP-ADDRESS/ui, got to your Host > "Services", and ensure that the TSM-SSH (SSH) Service is "Stopped". (Stop it and configure it to never start automatically if needed)

That's it ! You ESXI server is now 6.5 and the HP ILO was upgraded during the process.

:-)

Answer (score 1):

In GENERAL, it is advisable to use latest available, stable firmware version.
So if you are going to upgrade it - get the latest. 
If it won't be the version you need - you can always downgrade firmware to different one.

Answer (score 0):

Never just upgrade your iLO unless there's an actual bug/exploit that needs fixing - always apply the latest SPP instead - it'll update all of your system components to a level combination that is supported.

Comment: Hi, We initiated the upgrade in command-line, using : `esxcli software profile update -p ESXi-6.5.0-4564106-standard -d http://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml`. Then, the CLI said that we should upgrade the HP ILO before going forward. What do you mean by "SPP" ? What would be the better (and safer) way to obtain and apply this "SPP" ? Thanks Chopper3 ;)

Comment: http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx